# In Angular, why use a pipe instead of a native JavaScript function?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

What is the advantage of using an Angular pipe when a comparable native JavaScript function exists? For example:

```js
<input type="text" [value]="foo | uppercase">
```

vs.

```js
<input type="text" [value]="foo.toUpperCase()">
```

Answer (score 1):

`pipe` decorator `@Pipe` has `pure` option which is if `false` will listen to your changes of the variable passed in and `rerun` the pipe

With `pure: false` the `pipe` is evaluated each time Angular runs change detection.

also with `toUpperCase()` supose view will not evaluate your `ts` variable again